# Disentangle merge conflicts (tried to commit a file that was too big and screwed up)

Tags: git, github, ssh

It was a pretty simple task: commit a full directory and push it. Unfortunately, I forgot that one of my files exceeded the size limit, so I moved it away. Of course, it remained on my history so I tried to use

```
"git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

and a couple of more things but now I have a bigger problem (I DON'T KNOW WHAT I DID (!!)):

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
(use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

and

```
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
```

When trying to pull:

```
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in Peptide_count/notfound.tsv
Auto-merging Peptide_count/Hs_complex_map.fasta
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in Peptide_count/Hs_complex_map.fasta
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I'm desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't that far away from clearing this up. Go into the two files that have merge conflicts and clear them up, do a git commit -a, and git push back to your origin. How to resolve merge conflicts? see [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/fix-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: `git commit -a` takes me to a textfile, what does it mean to 'do it'?

Comment: Presumably you are in the VI text editor. Add your commit comments and exit the editor and upon exit, your commit will be comitted. Need help with VI? See something like http://www.howtogeek.com/102468/a-beginners-guide-to-editing-text-files-with-vi/